# Calculate proportion of study area covered by image on Google Earth Engine using a pixel count

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I want to calculate the proportion of a study area that is covered by (non null) pixels within an image. I have seen examples that do similar counts ([here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347335/reclassify-ndvi-and-count-number-of-pixels-above-certain-threshold-in-google-ear), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295876/count-pixels-of-different-bands-in-modis), and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339923/gee-select-images-that-have-certain-number-of-pixels)), and followed code from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354398/filter-imagecollection-to-images-with-non-masked-coverage-within-aoi-in-earth-en/354414#354414), but it doesn't seem to give the correct answer.

```
// get aoi feature
var aoi_ext = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[-3.0,53.0],
  [-2.5,53.0],
  [-2.5,53.5],
  [-3.0,53.5],
  [-3.0,53.0]]
  );


// Get image collection from Sentinel 2
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
  .filterBounds(aoi_ext) // just images intersecting with this
  .filterDate('2017-05-01', '2018-06-01') // %Y-%m-%d
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 80)
  .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'QA60']) 
  .map(function(image) { return image.clip(aoi_ext); }) // clip here to mask extent
  ;

print('no. images', collection.size());

// Look at first image
var img1 = ee.Image(collection.first());
print('image 1', img1);

// Display image
Map.addLayer(img1, {bands:['B2'], min: 0, max: 3000}, 'image 1');
Map.addLayer(aoi_ext, {}, 'aoi', true, 0.4);
Map.centerObject(aoi_ext);

// calculate number of all pixels in aoi

// get an image of aoi
var aoi_img = ee.Image(1).clip(aoi_ext);

// count pixels in aoi image
var totPixels = ee.Number(aoi_img.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 999999999,
  }).values().get(0));

// Count the non zero/null pixels in the image within the aoi
  var actPixels = ee.Number(img1.select('B2').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    scale: 10,
    geometry: aoi_ext, // need it here
    maxPixels: 999999999,
  }).values().get(0));

  // calculate the perc of cover
var pcPix = actPixels.divide(totPixels).multiply(100);

print('pixels in image:', actPixels, 'pixels in aoi', totPixels);

print('% cover', pcPix);
```

Looking at the display, I would estimate that about 15% was covered. With other images, it also clearly does not do the calculation I expect. I also tried masking the image with the result from a `.gte()` call, but it gives the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should restructure the code a bit. Unmask does (in your case) not unmask pixels outside the image extent. Thus, your variable `totPixels` is not right. Make an unbounded constant image, and apply `reduceRegion` with the crs and scale argument to calculate the number of total pixels with the same projection as your image:

```
// calculate number of all pixels in aoi

// count pixels in aoi image
var totPixels = ee.Number(ee.Image(1).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: aoi_ext,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 999999999,
  }).values().get(0));

// Count the non zero/null pixels in the image within the aoi
  var actPixels = ee.Number(img1.select('B2').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    scale: 10,
    geometry: aoi_ext, 
    maxPixels: 999999999,
  }).values().get(0));

  // calculate the perc of cover
var pcPix = actPixels.divide(totPixels).multiply(100);
```

[Link example](https://code.earthengine.google.com/33016d44db94c30e6fc0612d7b0a9b3f), with an addition to map it over the full collection. Two additional notes: clipping is generally not necesary and when working with Sentinel-2 imagery, always consider first [making daily composites](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348132/filter-out-incomplete-sentinel-2-images-in-earth-engine?rq=1). Then, you'll have unbounded composite images, which will work with the [previous example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354398/filter-imagecollection-to-images-with-non-masked-coverage-within-aoi-in-earth-en/354414#354414).

Comment: Thanks. There's a typo in your code here (carried through from the complete example) in totPix, crs should read "crs: img1.select('B2').projection()" so that it works with above example. Also, just to clarify, it's the clip that isn't somehow? extending beyond the image in my example? Unmask refers to the previous example.